# Single call to String.Concat() costs 11.23ms (according to unity profiler)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, profiling

Does anyone have any insight into why this call to String.Concat() seems to have cost 11.23 milliseconds?
Its in a frame with 900 calls to String.Concat due to a lot of logs being created. Is this just the garbage collector, or memory allocator? Is there a way that I can improve this?
[image: Profiler Screenshot]

For reference, this 60ms frame is created by me running my game with 800 actors (mostly not unity objects) to try and see where the performance bottlenecks are. Obviously the logging system is one of the largest bottlenecks in such a test.

Updated with an example of the sort of log operation being done with String.Concat():

```
Logger.Brain(actor, "Updating " + activeTask + " with time " + nextUpdateTimer);
```

With Logger.Brain being this:

```
public static void Brain(Actor actor, string text)
```

activeTask is a class with a ToString() override, and nextUpdateTimer is a float

That is the most common example. The contents of Logger.Brain are quite insignificant, performance wise.

Comment: How you use `String.Concat()` exactly, please provide a minimum code example

Comment: Please add code as text, not images.

Comment: Also, if it's the garbage collector that causes the longer than expected behaviour the profiler will tell you by showing you function calls starting by `GC.`

Comment: @Christopher that's a profiler picture not a code

Comment: @Menyus We need to code this profiler test was made from.

Comment: @Christopher i Know man that's what i requested also, but you said don't post codes as images but he posted a profiler picture which is completely fine :D

Comment: What are `activeTask` and `nextUpdateTimer`?  Are they also strings, or are they some other type for which you are implicitly calling the `ToString()` method?  Also, what is the `Logger.Brain()` method?  Are there overloads that take something other than a `string`?

Comment: @dbc activeTask is a class which has a ToString() override, nextUpdateTimer is a float. Logger.Brain looks like this: public static void Brain(Actor actor, string text) I'll update the question again.

Comment: Can you modify the `Logger.Brain` API?  If the contents are insignificant, performance wise then maybe you could modify it to take a `params String[] values` and log each component individually?

Comment: Hmm, looks like the [`public static String Concat(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, __arglist)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,3092) overload will get called.  Are you sure that `activeTask.ToString()` isn't what is taking the time?

Comment: @dbc What difference do you think that would make? According to the article you posted below by Jon Skeet, str1 + var1 + str2 would compile to a String.Concat call using a params String[] values anyway?

Comment: I don't know the unity profiler, but it might not be breaking out the time spent in `activeTask.ToString()` if it's called inside `string.Concat()`.  So your performance bottleneck might not be where you think it is.   Just a guess though.

Comment: The profile shows me that (in all 899 other cases) Object.ToString() is taking 1.89ms  total (800 instances), Single.ToString() is taking 5.39ms total (804 instances), and String.ConcatArray() is taking 2.52ms (900 instances). So it does appear to be accurately logging the constituents in the usual case (this screenshot is of a particularly unusual case)

Comment: It's typical for even old programmers to think that just because something is really concise in code it must also be fast. `String.Concat` is going to hit the memory manager, doing "free" and "malloc" under the skin. So it's going to cost you. Suggestion: reduce the number of times you build the string.

Comment: Have you considered doing Logger.Brain(actor, $"Updating {activeTask} with time {nextUpdateTimer}");

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on what you were *doing* with Concat that one time. Without that Information, we can at best guess. So here are my guesses:

String concatenation is both a memory and CPU heavy operation by default. Strings in .NET are inmutable - you never change one, you only create a new instance with a different values. Interally it is propably a char[], so it propably does a Array.Copy/List grow like operation during concat.

(This is not a guarantee, however. For really large strings concanetations some code might decide it is easier to make a linked list of the component strings and treat it like one string for all callers from the outside. However that too might have to be resolved back some time)

Also Concatenation is notorious for fragmenting the memory space. Normally the GC is really lazy at running - onc at application closure is the ideal case. It does still run before you ever get a OutOfMemory Exception. It could be that you ran into a "Danger of OOM Exception" scenario due to memory Fragmentation, so the GC had to put in a quick run of "emergency collecting and defragmenting everything" to finish this.

As I raed it, you have a total of 900 Concat calls. For limiting performance and memory impact of string concatenation use [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) instead of strings for as long as you can. Such amounts of concatenation is actually what that class is there for.

Comment: I see. Is there a clean way to use the StringBuilder on one line? I have logs printed as Log("const " + var + " const"); all over my scripts.

Comment: Given that OP is doing a small, fixed number of string concatenations defined at compile time, using `StringBuilder` may actually have worse performance.  See https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html for why.  `StringBuilder` is appropriate when building up a string from some variable inputs, e.g. in a loop.

Comment: @dbc Only some of the components are fixed, many of them are dynamically generated with an overridden ToString() function.
By small, I assume you mean that an individual operation is small (4-6 strings at most), although I am doing 900 of them.

Comment: @deek0146 - I mean fixed as in *fixed small number of arguments to `string.Concat()`*.  The values passed in may be variables, if they were constants the compiler would likely evaluate the expression at compile time.  `StringBuilder` is appropriate when building up a string from some variable number of inputs, e.g. in a loop.